# Using cloud VM but with local-physical NAS (keep data local)

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, local, nas

I've looked around for a means of keeping my data locally, behind a firewall (for example) while hosting my servers in the cloud. I checked out some NAS-like options but can't find any information on some that have been used for this.

Has anyone ever done this before?

Comment: What kind of data - a database?  files?  Are you going to use a web server  and application on your side so the cloud-based solution can talk to your NAS?  Otherwise, your data, locked securely behind a firewall, will be completely inaccessible.

Comment: The data would be on a system that exposes a network connection to the outside world (data would be files), through a firewall (as in the firewall would not close everything off); database is not part of this requirement. And yes, I would look for something with an server to handle the communication

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into FTP or webDAV implementations.  This question isn't really about programming... You might want to pick a different stack exchange site for your question.

Here are a couple places where you might get faster and better answers:

https://serverfault.com/

https://superuser.com/

Comment: That's fair; I mostly have programming experience; didn't think of looking for a more targeted forum. Much appreciated!